# Portability of a C code

Tags: c, portability

I have the following code

```
int main()
{
   int a=6;
   void *p;
   p=&a;
   p++;
}
```

Does the void pointer here increment by a particular value (if it is holding the address of any data type) ?

In the above case `p` increments by 1 even though it is pointing to an integer value. According to me the above code invokes `Implementation Defined` behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code in not valid from standard C point of view. It is illegal to increment `void *` pointers, or any other pointers to *incomplete* types.

Your compiler implements it as an extension, which is, of course, non-portable.

Answer (score 5):

Applying the ++ operator to `void*` is a GCC extension, which I'm told makes certain things a bit more convenient for very low-level programming (not having to cast so much, basically). I don't think I've ever hit a situation where I seriously don't want to cast to `unsigned char*`.

Use the `-pedantic` flag if you're writing code that's supposed to be portable.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the answer of [AndreyT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424912/portability-of-a-c-code/2424919#2424919):

Have a look at [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) which makes your code more portable.